# Android Studio: Autocomplete EditText input from massive data

Tags: java, android, json, autocomplete, android-edittext

I want to create a `EditText` input field in `Android Studio (Java)` that `autocompletes` the `Users input (City names in my case, with a unique ID for API call)`. From a website i got a `JSON` file with the `name` and the `corresponding ID`. Can anyone help me what is the best way to implement this autocomplete field? The file contains about 210 000 entries.

Comment: The main steps are to do a HTTP request to download the JSON file, then parse the JSON file into Java objects (Name + id), then implement a listener for the input field where you start searching in your Java City objects by name.
Likely, this file is a bit large, so you want to cache it on the device to avoid fetching it multiple times. While fetching the file you should show a busy indicator to the user. For steps 1-2 I recommend using the Retrofit framework.

Comment: I first tried to implement an autocomplete TextView with a String array ressource file but the app crashes (I think it is not performant enough). So you recommend creating a Class with members int id and String name, and create an object for every single city?

Comment: Yes. Your other option, which is more performant, is to store the values in a HashMap<String, Integer>